# How post Data (that is image or pdf converted to Byte array) to endpoint via Postman

Tags: c#, postman

I have an endpoint that I am sending data to using postman, I have a field that I can send image or pdf as byte array, how I can send data to it? I tried to use online tools to convert an image to byte array and send it, but it is breaking. I am trying to send like this, but it is not working:

```
 {
"Action": "SaveDocument",
"Appname": "test",
"AppUserID": "123",
"PatientID": "668833",
  .....
"Data": [49,48,58,50,52,58,50,54]
```

}

Also Is there any online tool you recommend using to convert image to Byte array so I can test endpoint via postman?

Server expect Byte array of document data.

I am getting this back when sending data,

```
       The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception message is 'There was an error
        deserializing the object of type Allscripts.UAI.Unity.UnityService.MagicInput. End element 'Data' from
        namespace '' expected. Found element 'item' from namespace ''.'. See server logs for more details. The
        exception stack trace is: </p>
```

Comment: How does the server expect it? Literally as you have there, an [array] of numbers between 0 and 255?

Comment: @Caisu, Server expects Byte array of document data.

Comment: I'm asking about how it wants it encoded, cos all in converting a bunch of bytes to a number-in-array representation is pretty space-wasteful.. It seems a surprising design decision on the part of the API creator..

Comment: what does *but it is breaking* and *but it is not working* mean, exactly?

Comment: @CaiusJard, I added what I am getting back from the server, this is the endpoint that is giving to me by another company to consume and I really don't know anything about it, before writing  the code I try to test it using postman, only thing that they have in the document is Data fields is Byte array of document data

Comment: Is that what you've put there exactly and completely what you're sending? It's not valid json if it is

Comment: @CaiusJard - I updated my querstion with the json I am sending, I don't have problem with other fields, I only don't know what to send in DATA.

Comment: What does the server side code that receives it look like? - it seems prehistoric, from the error message, but I suspect that it isn't expecting the array you're sending

Comment: @CaiusJard - it going to give me success code, so yes it is not expecting that, I only know I need to send Byte Array,

Comment: How do you know this? Who told you?

Answer (score 0):

you can use SMTP protocol to send this image as an Attachment, your code will be something like that :

using MailKit.Net.Smtp;
using MimeKit;

```
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage();
            BodyBuilder Attachmint = new BodyBuilder();
            message.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("name sender", "Mail From"));
            message.To.Add(MailboxAddress.Parse("Mail To"));
            message.Subject = Subject;
            message.Body = new TextPart("plain")
            {
                Text = tex_body.Text + Massage
            };

            Attachmint.Attachments.Add("Attatchment Path");
            message.Body = Attachmint.ToMessageBody();

            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
            client.Connect("smtp.gmail.com", 465, true);
            client.Authenticate("Mail from", "Password mail");
            client.Send(message);
```

Comment: Err... Right...